# javascript code executing after submit

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have some javascript code that is being executed before pressing submit button ,even the html form is not displayed.
What I want is to fill out a form and  these data input will be used in the controller.After that what is returned from  the controller will be used  in the javascript function.

I do not know why it doesn't work.

this is my code

```
@model highchart.Models.model2
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<html>

<body>
  <form Action="Index" method="post">

    <span> taux de change:"   </span>

    <input name="taux" value="EUR/USD" />
    <input type="text" id="txtId">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Date_début</th>
        <th>Date_fin</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="Date" name="date_début" id="date_début" value="@(Request.Form[" date_début "])"/>
        </td>


        <td>

          <input type="Date" name="date_fin" id="date_fin" value="@(Request.Form[" date_fin "])"/>
        </td>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="AFFICHE" name="affiche" onclick="storeInSession()" />
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function storeInSession() {
      window.sessionStorage['submit'] = document.getElementById('txtId').value;
    }


    function checkSubmitStatus() {
      if (window.sessionStorage['submit']) {

        ('#container').highcharts({
          title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
          },
          subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
          },
          xAxis: {
            categories: (function checkSubmitStatus() {
              var data = [];

              @foreach(var x in Model.temps) {
                @: data.push(@x);
              }
              alert(data[0]);

              return data;


            }())


          },
          yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
              value: 0,
              width: 1,
              color: '#808080'
            }]
          },
          tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
          },
          legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: (function checkSubmitStatus() {
              var data = [];

              @foreach(var x in Model.high) {
                @: data.push(@x);
              }
              alert(data[0]);

              return data;


            }())
          }]

        });


        window.sessionStorage['submit'] = '';
      }
    }

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you should probably format that code a little better.  and why do you have script tags outside of the <html> tag? and what is that @models tag?

Comment: I have written the javacript inside the <html> tag! and the @models is a class ! I have tested the javascript function and it works correctly but the problem with the synchronisation.

Comment: Can you also tag this with the appropriate templating engine you are using if any? You may get more relevant people to look at this. To me this looks like one of those cases of mixing server-side and client-side code.

Comment: Yeah, what @apokryfos said.  I don't recognize the templating engine, but i am getting a bad code smell from you reusing the name checkSubmitStatus for your functions over and over again...

Comment: I am using asp.net mvc

Comment: This looks like a general problem with executing server-side and client-side code and not really related to Highcharts. Do you have a problem with a chart?